# nginx node upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs server running behind nginx on elastic beanstalk. I think the following error is because of a promise that isn't being activated?

Does anyone have a better idea about what it is?

```
    2017/03/20 12:18:02 [error] 3503#0: *7363 upstream prematurely closed
 connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.11.11.111,
 server: , request: "POST /api/v1/some/url HTTP/1.1", upstream:
 "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/some/url", host: "some.website.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

we are also looking to solve that issue. From what I found, it looks like it is because your nodejs does not give a response fast enough. Hope it helps...